# @SectionedFetchRequest is not ordering correctly in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

I'm struggling with the `@SectionedFetchRequest` ordering system.

I have a `Word` object with 2 properties:

- `nameLanguageIdentifier` which represents the language code like it, fr, de, en, ...
- `name` which is the word like "boat"

In my list, I want my words to be ordered by `name` in sections ordered by `nameLanguageIdentifier`. Here is little example:

- Section 1: en

  - Bike
  - Boat
  - Car
- Section 2: fr

  - Arbre
  - Moto
  - Vélo

And so forth...

I wrote this fetch request:

```swift
@SectionedFetchRequest<String?, Word>(sectionIdentifier: \.nameLanguageIdentifier, sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
var words: SectionedFetchResults<String?, Word>
```

And here is my view body:

```swift
List(words) { section in
    Section(header: Text(section.id)) {
        ForEach(section) { word in
            Text(word.name)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get a totally random order. For example, I can have French words inside the English section.
I get rid of that behaviour when I use `nameLanguageIdentifier` both as section identifier and sort descriptor. But in this case, my words are no more ordered by name in their own section.

I really hope someone will be able to help me, Thank you so much.

Comment: Fix your sort descriptors so that the data is sorted the same way you want to display it.

Comment: Wait... You mean I have to specify in my sort descriptors the way I want to order my sections like `[SortDescriptor(\.nameLanguageIdentifier), SortDescriptor(\.name)]` ?

Comment: That's my understanding yes. I mean how else would SwiftUI know how you want your data ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @joakim mentionned, you have to specify all the sort descriptors you want to use, not only the one for your data into sections but the one for your sections too.

For my example, `[SortDescriptor(\.nameLanguageIdentifier), SortDescriptor(\.name)]` do the trick.